# How should I make a non-blocking server behavior in C when I only want to receive a single connection?

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking

In C, suppose I have a server application. The socket is setup properly and has been bound to a local port, and the listen() function has been called without error.

Code like this:

```
    //obtain a connection.
    int connection;
    struct sockaddr_storage sender;
    socklen_t addr_size = sizeof(sender);
    if((connection=accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sender, &addr_size))==-1)
            {close(sockfd); return -1; }
    if(close(sockfd)==-1){
            close(connection);
            return -1;
    }
    else
            return connection;
```

Successfully obtains a connection file descriptor through which data can be read from a client.

My application requires that the server wait for a finite amount of time, and then go off and do other things if no connection is made. Further, at most one connection will be accepted. Accept() is a blocking system call, but I would like to avoid blocking.

There seem to be many different ways to address this:

- A [SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892092/nix-c-writing-a-non-blocking-socket-server) suggests using select to solve this, but select is designed for monitoring many file handles at once, and seems like overkill here.
- Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794999/enable-non-blocking-socket) suggests modifying the socket to be non-blocking and then checking in a loop whether or not a connection was made. This would work also, but doesn't seem very nice because I do want to block - just not forever.
- In other languages I have seem people use SIGALARM and the alarm() command to prevent blocking, but my application has several threads, and this seems like an error-prone solution.
- In some other languages (Java?) I think there's a timeout argument that can be passed to accept which accomplishes this. That would be ideal here, but I can't seem to find a similar function for sockets in C.

Is there a nicer way to address this? It seems like the sort of thing someone else would have figured out already. If there isn't a nicer way, which of the solutions mentioned above is most appropriate? I'm leaning toward making the socket non-blocking, but it seems to introduce a large amount of extra cruft.

Comment: This is exactly what `select()` is for...waiting some amount of time for activity on one or more file descriptors.  Call `select()` with a timeout and you're got what you want.

Comment: `select()` is exactly what you need. Wrap it in a little function and it won't look like overkill either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using select remember to always make your file-descriptor non blocking with fcntl(), otherwise a client might initiate a connection, select would return, the client might terminate and your server would be blocked forever in the accept().

After a successful accept you might turn the file-descriptor into blocking mode again if your program works this way.